# Expansion of Logarithms with Cube Roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Does the following expand to the following
$$ \log_6(11^6\sqrt[3]{12}) $$

= $ 6\log_6(11) + \log_6 (\sqrt[3]{12})$

Comment: Almost there, just a little bit more expansion possible of the right-hand term.

Comment: would it be 1/3*logbase6(12)?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: ----thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

Yes and this is equal to $$6\log_6(11)+\frac{1}{3}(\log(2)+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

First note that
\[ \sqrt[n]{x}=x^{\frac{1}{n}} \]
\[ \log_{b}(xy)=\log_{b}(x)+\log_{b}(y) \]
\[ \log_{b}(x^{n})=n\log_{b}(x) \]
\[ \log_{b}(x)=\frac{\log_{10}(x)}{\log_{10}(b)}=\frac{\log(x)}{\log(b)} \]
So then
\[
\log_{6}(11^{6}\cdot\sqrt[3]{12})=\log_{6}(11^{6}\cdot 12^{\frac{1}{3}})=\log_{6}(11^{6})+\log_{6}(12^{\frac{1}{3}})=6\log_{6}(11)+\frac{1}{3}\log_{6}(12)
\]
Or perhaps
\[
\frac{6\log(11)}{\log(6)}+\frac{\log(12)}{3\log(6)}
\]

Comment: the 4th identity isn't quite so obvious.$$\begin{array}{lll}
a^{\log_aX}&=&X\\
(b^{\log_ba})^{\log_aX}&=&X\\
b^{\log_ba\cdot \log_aX}&=&X\\
\log_ba\cdot \log_aX&=&\log_bX\\
\log_aX&=&\frac{\log_bX}{\log_ba}\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @JohnJoy, true. I don't think any of those identities are obvious. I was just explicitly showing the OP how I arrived at my answer.

Comment: i wasn't criticizing. I thought that the OP may benefit from the derivation. :)